# How could I create a matrix, with each element being its own ID (i,j)?

Tags: java

How could I create a matrix, whose each element is its own ID (i,j)?

```
(0,0) (0,1) (0,2)...
(1,0) (1,1) (1,2)
(2,0) (2,1) (2,2)
.
.
.
```

How could I do it? And what is the data type of each component?

Thanks

Comment: A 2D array will do this.

Comment: thanks for replying. But what I want on each spot is a (0,0) or (0,1) or (i,j), not an int.

Comment: @SuicideBunny: your question is not clear to me. What do you mean to do with this? Display it in a GUI? Hold it as data? What?

Comment: I think he wants the row/column indices as a `int` -> `string` cast plus the brackets and the comma.

Comment: I am trying to think of a way to do one of the assignment using UnionFind to simulate Percolation. The example is given in 1D, where each element is corresponding to its ID, i am trying to do it in 2D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 2D array is declared as

```
int[][] array=new int[xSize][ySize];
```

I have used int as an example but any primative or reference type (such as String, Vector3d etc) can be used.

Once it is declared you can then access individual array elements

```
array[3][5]=17;
int someVariable=array[3][5];
```

Note technically this is an array of arrays and can be used as such, for example `array.length` is a valid line of code and returns xSize and array[0].length returns the ySize (**but** each of the inner arrays can be of differing lengths so this must be used with caution)

Comment: Primitive or reference type*.

Comment: The question has changed quite a bit, i'm going to wait till its clarified to edit further